# Template with non-integers and shifting

Tags: c++, templates, bit-shift

I have the following template function:

```
template<typename T> std::vector<T> foo::bar(std::vector<T> baz) {
    if (!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        return baz;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < baz.size(); ++i) {
             baz[i] <<= 1;
        }
        return baz;
}
```

If `T` is a `double` the compiler will complain

> '<<' illegal, left operand has type 'double'

Eventhough the shift operation will never be called.

Is there a way to inform the compiler that the shift is never going to be called?

Comment: template specialisation?

Comment: In C++17, you can use `if constexpr`.   For earlier versions of C++, you need to use template specialisation of the function, and not rely on `if` to do the check.

Comment: Apparently visual studio 2015 doesn't support most of C++17, so I'll have to use template specialisation.